# My game isn't working with Nvidia GeForce 7025/Nvidia nForce 630a

Tags: technical-issues, need-for-speed-most-wanted-2012

When I start Need For Speed Most Wanted (2012) I get the following error message:

> A DirectX10 or better graphics card is required. Please ensure you are using a supported graphics card with up to date drivers.

Does this mean that my graphics card is not compatible with NFS Most Wanted 2012?

Below is my current system specification:

```
Operating System:     Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit (6.1.Build 7600)
Memory:               2048 MB
Processor:            AMD Sempron 140 Processor ,2.7 GHz 
Direct X version:     Direct X 11
Graphics Card Detail: NVidia Geforce 7025/nForce 630a, total Memory: 889 MB
```

Is there any thing I miss to start this game?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The minimum requirements for NFS:MW 2012 include this:

> Graphics Card (NVIDIA): DirectX 10.0 compatible with 512 MB RAM (NVIDIA GEFORCE 8, 9, 200, 300, 400 OR 500 series with NVIDIA GEFORCE 8800 GT or higher performance)

Your video card, according to Wikipedia, only supports up to DirectX 9.

Unfortunately, you need to update your video card if you want to be able to play this game.